# transferring items among several arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, push, splice

I have got a pretty complicated issue, I tried everything and its not working properly. So the conception is (i just copied the interesting part of it, otherwise it would be few hundred more lines) :

The program is a card game and 24 cards (4 different colors, one is always stronger,it is called ADU) are distributed randomly among 4 players (4 arrays). The table where you put down the cards are represented by "asztal" array. First the human player puts a card, then the computers should reach in this order:

1. If they have same color and higher value - pick that card
2. If they have same color and any value - pick that card
3. If they dont have matching color, any car from the special color set (for being simple, its the first card the loop would find in the array)
4. If they dont have matching color, nor card from special color set, than the first element of the array (player[0]).

If you run my code, you would see it is not grabbing 1/1/1 card from each array, but sometimes more. And those cards do disappear, and not getting into the asztal array. My code: (https://jsfiddle.net/daxa3pL2/)

```
function CardA(name,value,adu){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
};
function CardB(name,value,adu){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
};
function CardC(name,value,adu){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
};
function CardD(name,value,adu){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
};
CardA.prototype.adu = false;
CardB.prototype.adu = false;
CardC.prototype.adu = false;
CardD.prototype.adu = false;
var a9 = new CardA("Tök kilenc",0);
var a10 = new CardA("Tök tíz",10);
var aal = new CardA("Tök alsó",2);
var afel = new CardA("Tök felső",3);
var akir = new CardA("Tök király",4);
var aasz = new CardA("Tök ász",11);
var b9 = new CardB("Levél kilenc",0);
var b10 = new CardB("Levél tíz",10);
var bal = new CardB("Levél alsó",2);
var bfel = new CardB("Levél felső",3);
var bkir = new CardB("Levél király",4);
var basz = new CardB("Levél ász",11);
var c9 = new CardC("Makk kilenc",0);
var c10 = new CardC("Makk tíz",10);
var cal = new CardC("Makk alsó",2);
var cfel = new CardC("Makk felső",3);
var ckir = new CardC("Makk király",4);
var casz = new CardC("Makk ász",11);
var d9 = new CardD("Szív kilenc",0);
var d10 = new CardD("Szív tíz",10);
var dal = new CardD("Szív alsó",2);
var dfel = new CardD("Szív felső",3);
var dkir = new CardD("Szív király",4);
var dasz = new CardD("Szív ász",11);
CardC.prototype.adu = true;
var player1 = [c9,b9,b10,d9,a9,d10];
var player2 = [a10,aal,dal,c10,cal,bal];
var player3 = [bfel,bkir,basz,dfel,dkir,dasz];
var player4 = [afel,akir,aasz,cfel,ckir,casz];
var asztal = [];
asztal.push(player1.splice(0,1)[0]);
var player2card1 = function() {
for (i = 0; i < player2.length; i++) {
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(player2[i]) == Object.getPrototypeOf(asztal[0]) && player2[i].value > asztal[0].value) {
        asztal.push(player2.splice(i,i+1)[0])
        return
    }
}
if (asztal.length == 1) {
for (i = 0; i < player2.length; i++) {
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(player2[i]) == Object.getPrototypeOf(asztal[0])) {
        asztal.push(player2.splice(i,i+1)[0])
        return
    }
}
}
if (asztal.length == 1){
    for (i = 0; i < player2.length; i++) {
    if (player2[i].adu == true)  {
        asztal.push(player2.splice(i,i+1)[0])
        return
    }
}
}
if (asztal.length == 1) {
    asztal.push(player2.splice(0,1)[0])
    return
}
        };
var player3card1 = function() {
for (i = 0; i < player3.length; i++) {
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(player3[i]) == Object.getPrototypeOf(asztal[0]) && player3[i].value > asztal[0].value) {
        asztal.push(player3.splice(i,i+1)[0])
        return
    }
}
if (asztal.length == 2) {
for (i = 0; i < player3.length; i++) {
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(player3[i]) == Object.getPrototypeOf(asztal[0])) {
        asztal.push(player3.splice(i,i+1)[0])
        return
    }
}
}
if (asztal.length == 2){
    for (i = 0; i < player3.length; i++) {
    if (player3[i].adu == true)  {
        asztal.push(player3.splice(i,i+1)[0])
        return
    }
}
}
if (asztal.length == 2) {
    asztal.push(player3.splice(0,1)[0])
    return
}
        };
var player4card1 = function() {
for (i = 0; i < player4.length; i++) {
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(player4[i]) == Object.getPrototypeOf(asztal[0]) && player4[i].value > asztal[0].value) {
        asztal.push(player4.splice(i,i+1)[0])
        return
    }
}
if (asztal.length == 3) {
for (i = 0; i < player4.length; i++) {
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(player4[i]) == Object.getPrototypeOf(asztal[0])) {
        asztal.push(player4.splice(i,i+1)[0])
        return
    }
}
}
if (asztal.length == 3){
    for (i = 0; i < player4.length; i++) {
    if (player4[i].adu == true)  {
        asztal.push(player4.splice(i,i+1)[0])
        return
    }
}
}
if (asztal.length == 3) {
    asztal.push(player4.splice(0,1)[0])
    return
}
        };
player2card1();
player3card1();
player4card1();
console.log(player1);
console.log(player2);
console.log(player3);
console.log(player4);
console.log(asztal);
```

Comment: I cant really understand what you were going for so I cant help you fix your problem but you can definitely clean that code up a bunch. Here is my first attempt: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLeXxw?editors=0010

Comment: sorry if i wasnt enough clear. Your code seems good, but it doesnt really do the thing it should achieve. Only one card from each array would go to asztal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I debugged your code and there are two fundamental mistakes I found:

1: When you use the splice inside a loop, the indices will change. So, when you do for example

```
 asztal.push(player2.splice(i,i+1)[0])
```

and put it inside a loop, the indices for player2 matching your condition will change as soon as you do the splice. So the next iteration of your loop will give incorrect results/ miss an index of an object that should be removed.

A possible solution to this is that instead of splice, inside your for-loops, just insert elements into asztal, and DON'T splice the parent. Then outside the loop, splice them from from the players using a FILTER function as follows:

```
 var player2card1 = function() {
 for (i = 0; i < player2.length; i++) {
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(player2[i]) == Object.getPrototypeOf(asztal[0]) && player2[i].value > asztal[0].value) {
       asztal.push({name: player2[i].name, value: player2[i].value, prototype: player2[i].prototype});
       player2[i].name = "delete";
       return
   }
}
player2.filter((each)=>{return each.name!== "delete"});
```

2: The second mistake (that I don't think is the problem here but still can cause trouble) is your use of "==". In Javascript, try to use '===' as far as possible as it also checks the type along with equality.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the easy explanation. One thing to notice. The problem is that now not only player2[i].name = "delete", but to asztal[1].name, asztal[2].name, asztal[3].name, too. The name values of objects in asztal array will be printed out later.

Comment: hey, yes you're right, I missed that. :) Have edited the answer. You need to create a new object and insert into the asztal, or just create a local copy of player2[i] and insert into asztal, anything would work.

Comment: Now another idea came actually. What if I SLICE the player2[i] and push it to the asztal array. And just right after the function run a loop on player2 array and SPLICE every item to another array (lets call it "trash") having undefined.

Comment: umm.. i didn't quite understand this method. but go ahead. try it out. :) the important thing is that you realized what was failing before.

Comment: asztal.push(player2[i]);
        delete(player2[i]);

This one seems doing the job actually.

Answer (score 0):

A little refactoring can go a long way to making this clear.

```js
// define a card type class
function CardType(type, adu)
{
 // This simply says that if ADU is undefined (not passed) then
  // ADU should be set to false by default
  this.adu = (typeof adu === 'undefined' ? false : adu);
  this.type = type;
}

function Card(name, value, type)
{
  this.name = name;
  this.value = value;
  this.type = type;
}

// Define our card types
var CardA = new CardType("A");
var CardB = new CardType("B");
var CardC = new CardType("C", true);// set to be ADU
var CardD = new CardType("D");

// Define our cards
var a9 = new Card("Tök kilenc",0, CardA);
var a10 = new Card("Tök tíz",10, CardA);
var aal = new Card("Tök alsó",2, CardA);
var afel = new Card("Tök felső",3, CardA);
var akir = new Card("Tök király",4, CardA);
var aasz = new Card("Tök ász",11, CardA);
var b9 = new Card("Levél kilenc",0, CardB);
var b10 = new Card("Levél tíz",10, CardB);
var bal = new Card("Levél alsó",2, CardB);
var bfel = new Card("Levél felső",3, CardB);
var bkir = new Card("Levél király",4, CardB);
var basz = new Card("Levél ász",11, CardB);
var c9 = new Card("Makk kilenc",0, CardC);
var c10 = new Card("Makk tíz",10, CardC);
var cal = new Card("Makk alsó",2, CardC);
var cfel = new Card("Makk felső",3, CardC);
var ckir = new Card("Makk király",4, CardC);
var casz = new Card("Makk ász",11, CardC);
var d9 = new Card("Szív kilenc",0, CardD);
var d10 = new Card("Szív tíz",10, CardD);
var dal = new Card("Szív alsó",2, CardD);
var dfel = new Card("Szív felső",3, CardD);
var dkir = new Card("Szív király",4, CardD);
var dasz = new Card("Szív ász",11, CardD);

var player1 = [c9,b9,b10,d9,a9,d10];
var player2 = [a10,aal,dal,c10,cal,bal];
var player3 = [bfel,bkir,basz,dfel,dkir,dasz];
var player4 = [afel,akir,aasz,cfel,ckir,casz];
var asztal = [];

// It doesn't really make sense to splice the array because
// you are changing the array. 
// asztal.push(player1.splice(0,1)[0]);
// This line can be replaced with a simple:
asztal.push(player1[0]);

// This function has lots of redundant code and we can simplify it greatly
// as well as generalize it to work for each player

function getNextCard(player, card){
 // By default we take the first card unless we find a better one along the way.
  var matchCase2 = null, // same type, any value
      matchCase3 = null, // special set
      matchCase4 = player[0]; // any card
  for(i = 0; i < player.length; i++)
  {
   // Check our first case
   if(player[i].type.type == card.type.type && 
        player[i].value > card.value){
     return player[i];
    }
    
    if(matchCase2 === null && player[i].type.type == card.type.type){
     matchCase2 = player[i];
    }
    
    if(matchCase3 === null && player[i].type.adu === true){
     matchCase3 = player[i];
    }
  }
  if(matchCase2 !== null) return matchCase2;
  if(matchCase3 !== null) return matchCase3;
  return matchCase4;
}

console.log(getNextCard(player2, asztal[0]));
console.log(getNextCard(player3, asztal[0]));
console.log(getNextCard(player4, asztal[0]));
```